# how to check token in local storage without crashing in react.js

Tags: reactjs

If I run the first line of this code the app comes crashing down, I have been trying to do this simple thing and redirecting for hours.

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken') || '';
console.log('token', token);
    
if (token != undefined) {
   console.log('a');
}
```

//error message

```
    InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified
./node_modules/jwt-decode/lib/index.js
D:/Code/bookreview/node_modules/jwt-decode/lib/index.js:9
__webpack_require__
D:/Code/bookreview/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
D:/Code/bookreview/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
```

Edit: I was running this code in some other file without  the if statement that was the problem. thanks

Comment: That's not a very informative error description...

Comment: Answered what looks like the problem, but if that's not it, this question could use more detail about what you're trying to do and the error message you're seeing.

Comment: Define crash? Any console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line of your code, `token` is always being assigned a value, so `token` is never `undefined`. Since the default returned by `getItem()` is `null` you could change your code to be:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken');
if (token) {
  ...
}
```

which will evaluate to true if `token` is not `null`, "", or some other [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.